# Display image url - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm editing a wordpress theme (colormag)

The theme has a nice function, but for them to work it is necessary to have an image highlighted in the post

My images are all attached from youtube or google image, preventing these functions from being used.

my alternative was to use the catch_image function see the code:

```
function catch_that_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

  if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
    $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
  }
  return $first_img;
}
```

When I add the function together with this code on the index page everything works

```
<img src="<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>" >
```

But when I try to use this theme widget (image)

[image]

The images are not as in the image, they are all big.

The code responsible for the widjet is this

```
<?php
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    $image           = '';
                    $thumbnail_id    = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
                    $image_alt_text  = get_post_meta( $thumbnail_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
                    $title_attribute = get_the_title( $post->ID );
                    if ( empty( $image_alt_text ) ) {
                        $image_alt_text = $title_attribute;
                    }
                    $image .= '<figure>';
                    $image .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title( '', '', false ) . '">';
                    $image .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, $featured, array(
                            'title' => esc_attr( $title_attribute ),
                            'alt'   => esc_attr( $image_alt_text ),
                        ) ) . '</a>';
                    $image .= '</figure>';
                    echo $image;
                }
                ?>
```

would it be possible to change this code so that it works together with the catch_that_image function?

So that he seeks the image of the article?